# How to install Ubuntu on hp pavilion g6

Tags: installation, hp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

The title says all. I want to install **ubuntu** on my hp pavilion g6

Comment: Please elaborate - are you facing problems on the install, or do not know *how* to install?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a simple installation procedure for Ubuntu. I don't know what problems are you facing while trying to install ubuntu on this HP pavilion g6. But the worst case would be to install ubuntu via the Alternate CD.

Anyway check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/91632) for all Ubuntu Installation Scenarios